# Why can't Java find a method?

Tags: java, methods

Apologies, as I am new to Java. I just started using methods, so I don't quite understand how they work yet.  I am creating a program that will take a time set in standard time (like HH:MM:SS) and convert it to am/pm time (for example, 2:35pm). I already have a few ideas for the program itself, but I am having issues with my method. The exact error is: "cannot find symbol". 
*EDIT* The error occurs on "convertToTraditional(standardTime)" method.
Here is the code:

```
package standardtime;

/**
 *
 * @author Owner
 */
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class StandardTime
{
    static String amPM;//will hold am/pm for standard time 
    static String traditionalTime;//will store traditional time from user
    static int mins1, mins2, hours;//will store hours and minutes

    public static void main (String args []) throws IOException 
 {BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));// user input

    int tryAgain=1;//will initial do-while loop
    System.out.println("Standard Time to Traditional Time Converter");
    System.out.println("===========================================");
    do{
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Input a time in Standard Form (HH:MM:SS):");
    String standardTime=br.readLine();//user inputs time in standard form
    System.out.println();



    do{
    if ((standardTime.length())!=8){
    System.out.println("Invalid time entered.");
    System.out.println("Input a time in Standard Form that has this form HH:MM:SS ...");
    standardTime=br.readLine();//user inputs time in standard form
    System.out.println();
    }
    }while((standardTime.length())!=8);
    //method declaration
    convertToTraditional(standardTime); // call the coversion method



    System.out.println(standardTime+" is equivalent to "+traditionalTime);
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Enter 1 to try again.");
    tryAgain=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());//user decides to try again
    }while(tryAgain==1);//will repeat if user enters 1

 }//closes main body
   public static void convertToTradtional(String standardTime)
   {
   String hour = standardTime.substring(0,1);
   hours = Integer.parseInt(hour);
   int hourNormal = hours - 12;
   Integer.toString(hourNormal);
   String minutes = standardTime.substring(3,4);
   traditionalTime = hourNormal + minutes;

    }


}
```

Comment: Sorry. I edited my original post. It is not finding the "convertToTraditional(standardTime);"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typo in your method declaration: `convertToTradtional`.